# Could a creature have multiple jaws?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, aliens

Recently I have been browsing theoretical alien designs and a feature I have become interested in are multiple jaws.

What I mean by this is an inner jaw located inside of the outer jaw. An example of this can be seen below (by artist [abiogenisis](http://abiogenisis.deviantart.com/art/Galkgrokst-Head-Study-323886714))

[image]

Is it possible for an animal to have a mouth inside of their mouth?

Comment: Considering 3 nearly identical answers within minutes of posting, I’d call this *insufficiently researched*.

Comment: @JDługosz I had researched this, but the Moray Eel never came up.

Comment: That’s just the example picture in Wikipedia.  goldfish, loaches, and many other fish have them.  HDE included a link in his answer, and I linked the picture directly to wikimedia commons and didn't copy it to imager, so you can find that url.

Comment: @JDługosz Huh, I never knew this, thanks for this knowledge

Comment: Sometimes *discovery channel* has real information!  Also fishing for “Nothern” in the channels off Lake Michigan can leave an impression on a kid  :)

Comment: IAC, google [animal with second set of jaws](https://www.google.com/search?q=animal+with+second+set+of+jaws) and the infobox shows that Wikipedia page, youtube videos, and bunches of sites who think it’s “news” every few years that this exists.

Comment: I actually can't see the second mouth?Jaw? in the alien picture. Where is it? Anyway I wonder whether a creature could have like 4-7 jaws/mouths inside each other like a Russian doll and what it might have been used for.

Comment: See near the end of the movie for the inner retractable jaws.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look no further than the moray eel.

[image]

While most other fish have pharyngeal jaws, those from the moray are highly mobile, probably as a turnaround to the problem that they can't chew.  The oral jaw snatches the prey, but the pharyngeal jaw drags it to the eel's gullet.

Answer (score 2):

[That is a real thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharyngeal_teeth).  Many families of fish have *pharyngeal jaws*, some very prominant like [*Alien*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_(creature_in_Alien_franchise)).

[image: fish]